# How to write an Apache Storm program

Tags: java, apache-storm

To write a program to submit to a storm cluster, does it need to be in a specific format or can I submit any basic program?

I'm trying to write as simple of a program as possible just to see if the cluster is working properly and to make sure I understand the software.

Comment: Does each program I write need a new pom.xml file or are they universal?

Comment: You should run storm-starter project in your cluster to check if everything is ok. It is from the storm team, so it has been tested a lot.

Answer (score 1):

A most basic program must implement a spout (ie, `IRichSpout` interface or `BaseRichSpout` class). Additionally, you must use `TopologyBuilder` to create a `StormTopology`. See here for a simple example:

> https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/master/examples/storm-starter/src/jvm/storm/starter/WordCountTopology.java

See here for a tutorial:

> https://storm.apache.org/documentation/Tutorial.html

Furthermore, you must package your code into a `jar` file and submit via `StormSubmitter`:

> https://storm.apache.org/documentation/Running-topologies-on-a-production-cluster.html

Answer (score 0):

To test the cluster, there are many programs already written. These programs are part of storm tar file. Use them directly.

Comment: I'm trying to write out all the specifics for my boss of how to submit a program to storm so I want to start from the beginning.  Issue is that I only have my freshman intro to programming and a basic data structure class as background.  Are there specifics that have to be in a program to make it eligible to be submitted to storm or can any program be submitted?